# Error when inserting a value to an array in Sanity.io

Tags: javascript, react-native, sanity

So I'm using sanity `.patch()` to insert data inside an array.
But I'm continously getting this error:

```
Error: insert(at, selector, items) takes an "at"-argument which is one of: "before", "after", "replace"
```

Here is my code for reference:

post.js

```js
// ...
{
        name: "peopleLiked",
        title: "People Liked",
        type: "array",
        of: [{ type: "string" }]
}
```

Where I'm using it:

```js
client.patch(id)
            .insert({
                "before": `peopleLiked.array[0]`,
                
                "items": [auth.currentUser.displayName]
            })
```

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insert syntax is wrong, looking at the [docs](https://www.sanity.io/docs/js-client#patch-update-a-document) it should be along the lines of:

`client.patch(id).insert('before', 'peopleLiked', [{"items": [auth.currentUser.displayName]}])`

I'm not familiar with Sanity but looks like you may also need to `.commit()` after the patch

Hope that helps